# TypeError: this.build(...).save is not a function

Tags: node.js, request, sequelize.js

hello i try to save the data to the database but its return error:

```
/home/ria/gajiandulu/gajiandulu-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2035
}).save(options);
```

Code:

```
var data = []
router.get('/',  (req, res,next) => {
    request('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/promos',  (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) { 
            res.json('An erorr occured')
            console.log(error)
        }
        else {
            let result = JSON.parse(body)
            res.send(result.data)
            data.push(result.data)
        }
        console.log(data + "ini")

        const save_data = Test.create(data)
        if (save_data) {
            return res
            .status(201)
            .json(true, 'data has ben retrieved')
        }else{
            return res.status(400).json(response(false, error))
        }
    });
});
```

anyone know whats wrong in my code
???????

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data + "ini")` ?

Comment: `[{"id":1,"code":"bg]fuydsafbdaoskla8ytsadf7a8sdu","discount":"10","expired_date":"2018-09-13","total":1111,"usage":1111,"created_at":"2018-09-12T00:00:00.000Z","updated_at":"2018-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"}]ini` thats the output

Comment: remove `data.push(result.data)` and change `Test.create(data)` to `Test.create(result.data)` , also check my answer for more detail

Comment: well,,  i will try

Comment: it doesnt work :(

Comment: I think you need to explore the basic syntax/function of node and sequelize after that I think you might get what I am trying to explain.

Comment: yes ofcourse thats what i need,,,, thankyou for helping me

Answer (score 7):

As you can see
`create` function accepts `Object` not `Array` ,

```
public create(values: Object, options: Object): Promise
```

And what you are passing is an `Array` :

```
var data = []; // <---- HERE
router.get('/',  (req, res,next) => {
    request('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/promos',  (error, response, body) => {
        ...
        else {
            ...
            data.push(result.data) // <---- HERE
        }
        console.log(data + "ini")
        ...
        const save_data = Test.create(data) // <---- HERE
        ...
    });
});
```

---

If you are searching for multiple row create , then you can use `bulkCreate` instead of just `create`

```
public static bulkCreate(records: Array, options: Object): Promise<Array<Model>>
```

Comment: still i dont understand how to implement it,, but i would try,, thanks

Answer (score 3):

First you set:

`var data = []`

Next an object is pushed into the array.

`data.push(result.data)`

The issue is here:

`Test.create(data)`

**.create** requires a "special object" **not an array**. It should be like the following.

`var create_data = {
name_of_column_in_database_1: data_to_go_into_that_column_1,
name_of_column_in_database_2: data_to_go_into_that_column_2
}`

Now you can say:

`Test.create(create_data)`

Example:
I have a column called "ticker" and I want to put some data that I get from the request, req.body.text.

My object that I send to the database with **.create** is like this:

`var create_data = {
ticker: req.body.text
}
Test.create(create_data)`

If you are still stuck post the column names you want data to go to and the values in **result.data** you want to put in each column.